# Div goes behind another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar, bootstrap-5

I just started with Bootstrap, and I cant figure out why the div goes behind the other div.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Fauske Simulator</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/style.css">
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
</head>

<body class="main-bg" scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../../index.html">Fauske Smiulator</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Ran noen på gata
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran/ran-privatperson.html">Ran en privatperson</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran/ran-offentlig-person.html">Ran en offentlig person</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran/ran-tilfeldig-gata.html">Ran en tilfeldig på gata</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Stjel en bil
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-bil-privatperson.html">Stjel fra en privatperson</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-bil-offentlig-person.html">Stjel fra en offentlig person</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-tilfeldig-gata.html">Stjel en tilfeldig på gata</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Stjel fra et hus
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-privat.html">Stjel fra et privat hus</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-offentlig.html">Stjel fra en offentlig byggning</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-gata.html">Stjel noe på gata</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-butikk.html">Stjel noe på fra en butikk</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Narkotika
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-traphouse.html">Hent varer fra TrapHouse</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-miks.html">Miks rusmidlene dine</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-ansett.html">Ansette dealere</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-selg-gata.html">Selg på gaten</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 profile-menu">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i> Min profil</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h fa-fw"></i> Account</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Settings</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i> Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="div-innpakning">
    <div class="border-info border-3 border-top side-navbar active-nav d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-column navbar-dark bg-dark" id="sidebar">
      <ul class="nav flex-column text-white w-100">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link h3 align-self-center text-white my-2">
            Lager
        </a>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-coins fa-fw"></i> Penger: </li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-car fa-fw"></i> Biler </li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-box-open fa-fw"></i> Ting </li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-pills fa-fw"></i> Narkotika </li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-3 d-flex" id="info">
      <p>h</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../../../js/navbar.js"></script>
  <script src="../../../js/sidebar.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Picture of website.
https://prnt.sc/1y8001u

The gray border goes behind the other div. Thats the problem.

How i want it.
https://prnt.sc/1y806jh

I want the div to be centered, not from start, but from the border-right on the sidebar and all the way right.

Comment: You should not be accepting random answers if you solved the problem yourself. Please post and accept an answer, or delete this question.

Comment: You have a bunch of invalid HTML up there. Edit the snippet to see the problems marked in red. It's invalid to directly nest list items, for example, and it's invalid to make an anchor element the child of a list element. You should be using a good editor or run your work through a validator.

Comment: @isherwood Its working, a lot of it is copy and paste.. Im using vsc. I changed the answer to my new post. Thanks :)'

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's working. That just means the browser is fixing things for you, which means it's guessing at what you meant. Good work is good work.

Comment: Can you point out exactly where its invalid html so i can fix it.

Comment: I explained what's wrong and how to see it above. What more can you ask for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sidebar had a position: absolute; Therefor the other div went behind the sidebar.

I made the sidebar and the other div to not collide.

Whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fauske Simulator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body onload="randomran()" class="main-bg" scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../../index.html">Fauske Smiulator</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Ran noen på gata
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ran-privatperson.html">Ran en privatperson</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ran-offentlig-person.html">Ran en offentlig person</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ran-tilfeldig-gata.html">Ran en tilfeldig på gata</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Stjel en bil
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-bil-privatperson.html">Stjel fra en privatperson</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-bil-offentlig-person.html">Stjel fra en offentlig person</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-tilfeldig-gata.html">Stjel en tilfeldig på gata</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Stjel fra et hus
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-privat.html">Stjel fra et privat hus</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-offentlig.html">Stjel fra en offentlig byggning</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-gata.html">Stjel noe på gata</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-butikk.html">Stjel noe på fra en butikk</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Narkotika
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Narkotika/narkotika-traphouse.html">Hent varer fra TrapHouse</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Narkotika/narkotika-miks.html">Miks rusmidlene dine</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Narkotika/narkotika-ansett.html">Ansette dealere</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Narkotika/narkotika-selg-gata.html">Selg på gaten</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 profile-menu"> 
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i> Min profil</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h fa-fw"></i> Account</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Settings</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="div-innpakning" class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="">
    <div class="col-3 border-info border-3 border-top side-navbar active-nav d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-column navbar-dark bg-dark" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav flex-column text-white w-100">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link h3 align-self-center text-white my-2">
            Lager
        </a>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-coins fa-fw"></i> Penger: </li>
        </li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-car fa-fw"></i> Biler </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-box-open fa-fw"></i> Ting </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-pills fa-fw"></i> Narkotika </li>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center" id="info">
      <div id="info01" class="border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column">
        <p class="fs-1 text-center">Ran en privatperson.</p>
        <div class="align-self-center justify-content-center">
        <p class="fs-2 text-center">Hvem vil du rane?</p>
        <div class="align-self-center"> 
      </div>
    </div>
      <button onclick="randomran()" id="finn_ran" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary w-50 align-self-center">Finn ransoffer - Pris: 500kr</button>
      <p id="ranoffer" class="align-self-center"></p>
      <p class="fs-5 align-self-center" id="sjanse"></p>
      <p class="fs-5 align-self-center" id="penger_nivå"></p>
      <div class="form-check align-self-center">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" onclick="våpen()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
          Vil du bruke et våpen? - Pris: 2 000kr
        </label>
      </div>
      <button onclick="utfør_ran()" id="utfør_ran" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary w-50 align-self-center">Utfør ran</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../../js/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/sidebar.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/script.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body><script src="/node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
<p id="lagre"></p>
<p id="lagre01"></p>
<p id="lagre02"></p>
</html>
```

Only the div:

```
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center" id="info">
      <div id="info01" class="border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column">
        <p class="fs-1 text-center">Ran en privatperson.</p>
        <div class="align-self-center justify-content-center">
        <p class="fs-2 text-center">Hvem vil du rane?</p>
        <div class="align-self-center"> 
      </div>
    </div>
      <button onclick="randomran()" id="finn_ran" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary w-50 align-self-center">Finn ransoffer - Pris: 500kr</button>
      <p id="ranoffer" class="align-self-center"></p>
      <p class="fs-5 align-self-center" id="sjanse"></p>
      <p class="fs-5 align-self-center" id="penger_nivå"></p>
      <div class="form-check align-self-center">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" onclick="våpen()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
          Vil du bruke et våpen? - Pris: 2 000kr
        </label>
      </div>
      <button onclick="utfør_ran()" id="utfør_ran" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary w-50 align-self-center">Utfør ran</button>
      </div>
      </div>
```

The div with id "info" covers the whole page, but doesnt go over the sidebar and navbar. Then the div with id "info01" is placed in the middle of the info div.

CSS:

```
#info {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

The body is min-height 100vh.

Answer (score 0):

add the row class in  and add to the child div the col class according to the desired configuration, more information about Grid System, you can check inhttps://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fauske Simulator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/style.css">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
</head>
<body class="main-bg" scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../../index.html">Fauske Smiulator</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Ran noen på gata
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran/ran-privatperson.html">Ran en privatperson</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran/ran-offentlig-person.html">Ran en offentlig person</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran/ran-tilfeldig-gata.html">Ran en tilfeldig på gata</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Stjel en bil
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-bil-privatperson.html">Stjel fra en privatperson</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-bil-offentlig-person.html">Stjel fra en offentlig person</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Stjel bil/stjel-tilfeldig-gata.html">Stjel en tilfeldig på gata</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Stjel fra et hus
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-privat.html">Stjel fra et privat hus</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-offentlig.html">Stjel fra en offentlig byggning</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-gata.html">Stjel noe på gata</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Ran hus/stjel-hus-butikk.html">Stjel noe på fra en butikk</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Narkotika
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-traphouse.html">Hent varer fra TrapHouse</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-miks.html">Miks rusmidlene dine</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-ansett.html">Ansette dealere</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="narkotika-selg-gata.html">Selg på gaten</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 profile-menu"> 
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i> Min profil</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h fa-fw"></i> Account</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Settings</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="div-innpakning" class="row">
    <div class="col-3 border-info border-3 border-top side-navbar active-nav d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-column navbar-dark bg-dark" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav flex-column text-white w-100">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link h3 align-self-center text-white my-2">
            Lager
        </a>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-coins fa-fw"></i> Penger: </li>
        </li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-car fa-fw"></i> Biler </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-box-open fa-fw"></i> Ting </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <li class="nav-link h6 text-white my-2"><i class="fas fa-pills fa-fw"></i> Narkotika </li>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col border border-3" id="info">
        <p>h</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../../js/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/sidebar.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually dont know if the answer worked, I couldnt understand the explanation.. But i got it another way.